# How to dynamically change the tick spacing of x-axis of a timeseries in chart.js when zooming enabled?

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I have a chart that is based on 5-minute resolution data. If a user chooses to display 5 days worth of data, I want the x-axis to update from a "day" format like 'Jan 1' to more granular like format like "hour" and "minute" on zoom. I think I'm pretty close to figuring it out, I just can't figure out how to start my chart with the "day" format. Right now, it automatically chooses to start at "hour" and spaces the ticks closer together and as I zoom, it goes down to minute.

**Currently, this is how my chart starts (there is data that shows, I just can't share it here):**
[image]

**Ideally, I'd like my chart to start with just sparse day tick marks, like this:**
[image]

**And as I zoom in, it'd work down to the hour, then the minute format which would display denser tick marks:**
[image]

I am using chartjs version 4.3.0.

```
//timeAxis is array of dates
timeAxis = [Fri Jan 01 2021 00:05:00, Fri Jan 01 2021 00:05:05, ..., Fri Jan 05 2021 24:00:00]
flowData = [{label: 00:05:00, value: 27}, {label: 00:05:05, value: 28}, ..., {label: 24:00:00, value: 32}]

const data = {
    //labels is the x-axis values
    labels: timeAxis,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Total Plant Flow (Cubic Feet)',
        backgroundColor: dataAndModelsList[0].color,
        borderColor: 'black',
        data: flowData.map(({ value }) => value),
        yAxisID: 'y1'
      }
    ]
  }

const options: ChartOptions<'line'> = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    aspectRatio: 2, 
    scales: {
      y1: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Total Plant Flow (Cubic Feet)',
        },
        position: 'left'
      },
      x: {
        display: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Time'
        },
        type: 'timeseries',
        min: timeAxis[0].toString(),
        max: timeAxis.pop().toString(),
        time: {
          minUnit: 'minute',
          displayFormats: {
            //year: 'yyyy',
            //month: 'MMM',
            day: 'MMM dd',
            hour: 'MMM dd H:mm',
            minute: 'MMM dd H:mm:ss'
          }
        },
        ticks: {
          source: 'data'
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
        position: 'bottom',
        labels: {
          boxWidth: 0
        }
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Total Plant Flow at 5 Minute Intervals'
      },
      zoom: {
        zoom: {
          drag: {
            enabled: true
          },
          mode:'x'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to set "unit: 'day'" in time node of scale options?

Comment: @user2057925 Yes, what that does is it sets the chart to only allow the units in the day format. It will not dynamically adjust at all if you set that.

Comment: using zoom, you could change the scale options, using the onZoomComplete hook of the plugin and then update the chart with new time unit.

Comment: Codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/QWZyvZm maybe it helps